# On linux kernel, I want to set user default bash command about alias and export. How can I do it?

Tags: linux, bash

I began Linux kernel to operate CFD solver on HPC.

then, I am creating my development environment.

I wrote this code to set alias and export.

but, I run my bash command like ll, v,...

It prints only command not found.

How can I fix it?

'''
`function callMyShellFn()`

```
{
    alias cp='cp -i'
    alias ll='ls -l'
    alias la='ls -A'
    alias l='ll'

    alias ls="pwd && ls --color=auto"
    alias ll="ls -lh --color=auto"

    alias mv="mv -i"
    alias rm="rm -i"
    alias v="vim ./"
    alias ff="find -iname"
    alias e='exit'

    alias loadbash="source ~/.bashrc"

    alias grepnr="grep -nr"

    alias tarCompress="tar -czvf"
    alias tarExtract="tar -xzvf"
    alias xmgraceAll="xmgrace -nxy"

    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\W\$'
}

function setDefaultUserBash()
{
    callMyShellFn
    callLIGERFn
}



function callLIGERFn()
{
    export THE_USSER="myname"
    export THE=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/home/$THE_USSER
    export THEhan=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/home/$THE_USSER
    export SCRATCH=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/scratch/$THE_USSER
    export SMLEXT=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/home/$THE_USSER
    export SCRATCHEXT=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/scratch/$THE_USSER
    export HanWORK=$THE_USSER"@00.000.000.00:"/home/$THE_USSER/Work
    alias rsync="rsync -azP"
    alias rsyncTHE="rsync -azP --rsh='ssh -p0000'"
}


### Set user default bash command
setDefaultUserBash`
```

Comment: In the Bash manual from pre-1996 we find the line "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."  There is no reasons for anyone, anywhere, ever to continue using aliases in their interactive shells.   This is not quite true as there is at least one extreme edge case where auto-expansion works a little more cleanly, but that small edge case (which you the reader almost certainly do not care about) does not justify the confusion that aliases tend to introduce!

Comment: Generally, you should define shell features that you want available in all user's shells in `/etc/bashrc` or in `/etc/profile`, or similar.    In what file are you invoking `setDefaultUserBash`?

Comment: If you insist on using aliases, the place to define those is in only a personal **.bashrc_local**.  Those should never be defined in the system master default files for .bashrc.  The recommended method is that you create a one-liner command script whose name is your original alias, **except** for those cases where the alias "**reused**" the OS-supplied utility/command name.  You will need to create a new unique name for those.